# Unable to convert webcontrol to generic type in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have the below method that I am using to create webcontrols (for now just literal and Panel)

```
private T CreateControl<T>(string s1, string s2, string m1)
    where T: WebControl , new()
{
    T ctrl = default(T);

   if (ctrl is Literal )
    {
       Literal l = new Literal();
       l.ID = s1 + "ltl" + s2;
       l.Text = s1 +  " " + s2;
       ctrl = (Literal)l;
    }
    else if (ctrl is Panel)
    {
        Panel p  = new Panel();
        p.ID = s1+ "pnl" + s2;
        p.CssClass = s1 + "graphs";
        p.Attributes.Add("responsefield", s2);
        p.Attributes.Add("metricid", m1);
        ctrl = (Panel)l;

    }
    else if (ctrl is CheckBox)

       return ctrl;
}
```

I am invoking this as:

```
Literal lg = CreateControl<Literal>("emails", name.Name, name.MetricId.ToString() );
```

But the conversion is failing at:

```
ctrl = (Literal)l;
ctrl = (Panel)p;
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' to 'T'
```

Can somebody advise how to handle this conversion?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried `ctrl = l As Literal;` and `ctrl = p As Panel;`?

Comment: As far as I know, Literal does not inherit from WebControl. You have to go one step up to Control

Comment: @jbl, initially I have tried with Control itself, that too didnt work.

Comment: @Tim, same error with l as literal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you something like this.

```
private T CreateControl<T>(string s1, string s2, string m1)
where T : System.Web.UI.Control,new()
{

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Literal))
    {
        Literal l = new Literal();
        l.ID = s1 + "ltl" + s2;
        l.Text = s1 + " " + s2;
        return l as T;
    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Panel))
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.ID = s1 + "pnl" + s2;
        p.CssClass = s1 + "graphs";
        p.Attributes.Add("responsefield", s2);
        p.Attributes.Add("metricid", m1);
        return p as T;

    }
    else if (typeof(T) == typeof(CheckBox))
    {
        return new CheckBox() as T;
    }
    else
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Edit: Modified the method you don't need to cast it afterwars like @jbl suggested.

```
Literal l = CreateControl<Literal>("something", "something", "something");
```

Comment: It might be safer to do `Literal l = CreateControl<Literal>("something", "something", "something") as Literal;` - then you can check `l` to see if it's null or not.  If the conversion fails, it will be null.

Comment: "So you need to cast it afterwards." Unless you cast it in method : "return new CheckBox() as T;" Then you should be able to have _private T CreateControl ..._